# Finding probability for atleast

Tags: probability

I have a doubt in a question which is
There are 5 components(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5) in a system and the probability that a component will work is q. i have to find the probability that at least three components works in the system?

Comment: You might want to check https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question belonging to Stack Overflow